# java node.appendChild is not removing previous tag

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm trying to merge two XML documents, there are two simple examples:

**Design XML:**

```
<element type="INPUT-TEXT">
    <id>id1</id>
    <name>Id1</name>
    <order>1</order>
    <required>false</required>
</element>
```

**Answer XML:**

```
<form>
    <id1>answer1</id1>
</form>
```

I'm iterating trough Design XML nodes, when I find the `<id>` tag text (id1), I iterate trough Answer XML and I search the `<id1>` tag name and I add it to the Design XML in this way:

```
<element type="INPUT-TEXT">
    <id>id1</id>
    <name>Id1</name>
    <order>1</order>
    <required>false</required>
    <answer>answer1</answer>
</element>
```

This is correct, but if I try to do the same again, I get a duplicate answer tag:

```
<element type="INPUT-TEXT">
    <id>id1</id>
    <name>Id1</name>
    <order>1</order>
    <required>false</required>
    <answer>answer1</answer>
    <answer>newAnswer1</answer>
</element>
```

And I need to override the answer tag value.
This is my Java method which use the `appendChild` method:

```
public String createEditableXML(String xml) {

        try {
            Document document;
            Document documentAnswer;

            document = _loadXMLFromString(xml);
            documentAnswer = _loadXMLFromString(vars);

            String child = null;

            // Design xml part
            NodeList nodeList1 = document.getChildNodes();
            NodeList nodeList = nodeList1.item(0).getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && node.getNodeName().equals("element")) {

                    // Taking id to compare with the answer XML
                    NodeList childNode = node.getChildNodes();
                    for (int n = 0; n < childNode.getLength(); n++) {
                        if (childNode.item(n).getNodeName().equals("id")) {
                            child = childNode.item(n).getTextContent();
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // Adding the anwser to the original document
                    NodeList answerNodeList = documentAnswer.getElementsByTagName("*");
                    for (int m = 1; m < answerNodeList.getLength(); m++) {
                        Node answerNode = answerNodeList.item(m);
                        if (answerNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                            if (child.equals(answerNode.getNodeName())) {
                                Element answer = document.createElement("answer");
                                answer.appendChild(document.createTextNode(answerNode.getTextContent()));
                                node.appendChild(answer);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return _nodeListToString(nodeList1);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            String mess = "createEditableXML(): " + (e.getMessage() != null ? ". " + e.getMessage() : "")
                    + (e.getCause() != null ? ". " + e.getCause() : "");
            logger.error(mess);
        }
        return null;

    }
```

The method explanation says that will replace the answer tag by the new one.

> Node org.w3c.dom.Node.appendChild(Node newChild) throws DOMException
>
> Adds the node newChild to the end of the list of children of this
>   node. If the newChild is already in the tree, it is first removed.

Some idea?

Comment: Text nodes are not compared by their content.

Comment: newChild is not removed, because you create a new Node object, method createTextNode(), everytime you append. If you added newChild and tried to add exactly the same object, then the old one would be removed. Either find a way to save answer textNode references or update through DOM directly.

Comment: @CrazySabbath Ok, I can try something like you propose, but there is not another way to do that in a "clean" way, without getting previously the node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** newChild is not removed, because you create a new Node object, method createTextNode(), everytime you append. If you added newChild and tried to add exactly the same object, then the old one would be removed. Either find a way to save answer textNode references

**Option 2:** When you find a matching ID check if answer node already exists, and if it does, update it instead of appending a new answer node. That way you don't have to save references from previously created answer nodes.

Example (Code is not tested, it's just an idea to help you move forward):

```
//I suggest to use constants
private static final String ANSWER_NODE_NAME = "answer";

// Adding the anwser to the original document
NodeList answerNodeList = documentAnswer.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (int m = 1; m < answerNodeList.getLength(); m++) {
    Node answerNode = answerNodeList.item(m);
    if (answerNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        if (child.equals(answerNode.getNodeName())) {


            //Check if answer node already exists
            //if it does, update its content instead of appending a new answer node
            NodeList children = node.getChildNodes();

            boolean answerNodeExists = false;
            for(int j = 1; j < children.getLength(); j++){
                Node origDocumentChild = children.item(j);

                //check if node is <answer>
                if (origDocumentChild.getNodeName().equals(ANSWER_NODE_NAME)) {

                    //set new answer content
                    origDocumentChild.setTextContent("new answer 123");
                    answerNodeExists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!answerNodeExists) {
                Element answer = document.createElement("answer");
                answer.appendChild(document.createTextNode(answerNode.getTextContent()));
                node.appendChild(answer);
                break;
            }               
        }
    }
}
```